# Date format conversion in Excel

Tags: excel, datetime

I have a list of dates, which seem to be in `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm format ( Ex - 12/13/2022 12:16 AM )` , which is incorrect. I need to change to `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm` format.

I tried the formula `=IF(H2="","",IF(DAY(H2)>12,DAY(H2)&"/"&MONTH(H2)&"/"&YEAR(H2),VALUE(DATE(YEAR(H2),DAY(H2),MONTH(H2)))))`

but the result is `#Value`

[image: Example]

[image]

Comment: Are they text on cells?

Comment: They seem to be in general format. I tried using format cells to get the data from dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm to mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm format, but it doesnt work.

Comment: How did the values get onto the worksheet?  Were you merely supplied the worksheet or did you open a CSV file? What is the result of the formula `=ISNUMBER(cell_ref)` where `cell_ref` represents a datetime entry that is returning the error when used in your formula? If the data came from a CSV file, you should **import** the file using either Power Query or the legacy text import wizard, and set the data type correctly in that wizard (should be set to MDY if that is how the dates are stored in the CSV file)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the point: a datetime format in Excel is a normal number, where 1 means one day, starting at the first of January, 1900.

Let me show how it looks on my PC:

[image]

As you can see, there are two ways to describe the thirteenth of December, 2022:

- format `dd/mm/yyyy` : `13/12/2022` (European style)
- format `mm/dd/yyyy` : `12/13/2022` (American style)

But as you can see below, the actual values are the same (`44908` is the amount of days starting at January first 1900).

Doing calculations on this, like checking `=DAYS()>12`, has no meaning, because the days will be calculated from that 44908 number, not from the way it's displayed.

So, don't start formulas on that, just alter the way it's displayed (using cell formatting, as shown in my screenshot).

Comment: So, don't start formulas on that, just alter the way it's displayed (using cell formatting, as shown in my screenshot). - I tried doing this with format cell, but the cell is not getting formatted. It is giving same result for mm/dd or dd/mm.
Also to highlight, if I use the weeknumber on 12/1/2022 1:08 AM , I am getting output as 3, which indicates the excel is considering it as January. I used the formula =IF(A2="","",IF(DAY(A2)>12,DAY(A2)&"/"&MONTH(A2)&"/"&YEAR(A2),VALUE(DATE(YEAR(A2),DAY(A2),MONTH(A2))))) on 12/1/2022 1:08 AM and then when I check wht week number it is reflecting as 49.

Comment: This however doesnt work from 12/13/2022 12:16 AM.

Comment: I am not able to upload the file, else could have explained the case better.

Comment: I have the impression that Excel does not recognise those entries as dates, it just sees those as meaningless strings, so you can't perform date-related functions on it. Try to figure out what you can do in order to make Excel understand the format and go on from there.